# How to filter objects based on whether an array field contains a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have a React app, and I want to filter objects that are in a particular 'category'. On the category object, there is a 'links' field that is an array of Id's. I'm able to get that array and put it into `catLinks`, below. The objects that I want to filter through are in the `json` object.

What is confusing me is that the filter I am using does return true when I would expect it (as seen in the console log), but then nothing is returned in the `filtered` object.

```
console.log('catLinks: ', catLinks)
// returns 'catLinks: [649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6]'

const filtered = json.filter((l) => {
   catLinks.forEach((catLink) => {
      if(catLink == l._id) {
          console.log(l._id, 'is true')
          // returns '649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6 is true'
          return true
      }
      console.log(l._id, 'is false')
          return false
      })
}).length > 0
console.log('filtered \n', filtered);
// returns 'filtered
//           false'
```

Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong here?

I have tried using includes() as well as the method above, and can not get it to work.

Comment: forEach does not return a value.... You are trying to reinvent some(), but includes would be cleaner.

Comment: You've tagged `mongodb` but not referenced it at all in the question.  Do you want to push some of this logic into the database query? If so, we'd need to know more about the existing document structure. If not then the tag should be removed

Answer (score 1):

On javascript, if you want to filter an array you can simply use `filter`:

```
const json = [{_id: '649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6'}, {_id: '649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf9'}]
const catLinks = ['649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6', '649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf7', '649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf8']
const filtered = json.filter(x => catLinks.includes(x._id))
console.log(filtered)
```

to get:

```
[{_id: "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6"}]
```

But if `json` is a result of a mongodb query, you can get this directly from the query using `$in`...

For example:

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: {
    $in: [
      "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6",
      "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf7",
      "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf8"
    ]
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/28FbPckkGIg)

*updated to use `includes` instead of `indexOf`, according to a remark by @epascarello

Comment: I don't want to filter `catLinks`, I want to filter `json` for when `json._id` exists in `catLinks`

Comment: Yes, an array of objects

Comment: In this case, I updated the answer

Comment: Array includes() would be cleaner.